# Something faster than std::nth_element

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, kdtree

I'm working on a kd-tree implementation and I'm currently using **std::nth_element** for partition a vector of elements by their median. However std::nth_element takes 90% of the time of tree construction. Can anyone suggest a more efficient alternative?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're doing this repeatedly to find the median of the whole, then the median of each half, and so on, it may be faster to just use `std::sort` once, then each median will be in the correct place.

Comment: The probem with this is that you need to partition once by x median, then by y median, then z median...in round robin fashion (or you partition by the axis of the longest edge of the bounding box of the subregion). So I would need to sort the whole vector three times at the beginning, once by x, y and z.

Comment: Yes, I figured that--have you tried it? I'm not sure it'll end up faster, but it seems like it would be easy to test, and might easily work out well.

Comment: What's the code like (distilled version)? I get the impression that your "kd-tree" implementation is a big bag of data and you just keep shuffling it (using `nth-element`) each time you search... if there is no code, then you'll only get generic "best guess" advices.

Comment: It takes 90% of the time.  That may be good if it is doing 90% or more of the actual work!  Rather than thinking about doing work more efficiently, maybe do less work?

Comment: btw: you can also save a lot of time constructing a kd-tree if you allocate the memory for all nodes as one chunk (array) in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you really need the nth element, or do you need an element "near" the middle?

There are faster ways to get an element "near" the middle.  One example goes roughly like:

```
function rough_middle(container)
  divide container into subsequences of length 5
  find median of each subsequence of length 5 ~ O(k) * O(n/5)
  return rough_middle( { median of each subsequence} ) ~ O(rough_middle(n/5))
```

The result should be something that is roughly in the middle.  A real nth element algorithm might use something like the above, and then clean it up afterwards to find the actual nth element.

At `n=5`, you get the middle.

At `n=25`, you get the middle of the short sequence middles.  This is going to be greater than all of the lesser of each short sequence, or at least the 9th element and no more than the 16th element, or 36% away from edge.

At `n=125`, you get the rough middle of each short sequence middle.  This is at least the 9th middle, so there are 8*3+2=26 elements less than your rough middle, or 20.8% away from edge.

At `n=625`, you get the rough middle of each short sequence middle.  This is at least the 26th middle, so there are 77 elements less than your rough middle, or 12% away from the edge.

At `n=5^k`, you get the rough middle of the `5^(k-1)` rough middles.  If the rough middle of a `5^k` sequence is `r(k)`, then `r(k+1) = r(k)*3-1 ~ 3^k`.

`3^k` grows slower than 5^k in O-notation.

```
3^log_5(n)
= e^( ln(3) ln(n)/ln(5) )
= n^(ln(3)/ln(5))
=~ n^0.68
```

is a very rough estimate of the lower bound of where the `rough_middle` of a sequence of `n` elements ends up.

In theory, it may take as many as approx `n^0.33` iterations of reductions to reach a single element, which isn't really that good.  (the number of bits in n^0.68 is ~0.68 times the number of bits in n.  If we shave that much off each rough middle, we need to repeat it very roughly `n^0.33` times number of bits in n to consume all the bits -- more, because as we subtract from the `n`, the next `n` gets a slightly smaller value subtracted from it).

The way that the nth element solutions I've seen solve this is by doing a partition and repair at each level: instead of recursing into `rough_middle`, you recurse into `middle`.  The real middle of the medians is then guaranteed to be pretty close to the actual middle of your sequence, and you can "find the real middle" relatively quickly (in O-notation) from this.

Possibly we can optimize this process by doing a more accurate `rough_middle` iterations when there are more elements, but never forcing it to be the actual middle?  The bigger the end `n` is, the closer to the middle we need the recursive calls to be to the middle for the end result to be reasonably close to the middle.

But in practice, the probability that your sequence is a really bad one that actually takes n^0.33 steps to partition down to nothing might be really low.  Sort of like the quicksort problem: median of 3 elements is usually good enough.

---

A quick stats analysis.

You pick 5 elements at random, and pick the middle one.

[The median index of a set of `2m+1` random sample of a uniform distribution follows the beta distribution with parameters of roughly `(m+1, m+1)`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289520/median-of-a-uniform-distribution-0-1), with maybe some scaling factors for non-`[0,1]` intervals.

The mean of the median is clearly 1/2.  The variance is:

```
(3*3)^2 / ( (3+3)^2 (3+3+1) )
= 81 / (36 * 7)
=~ 0.32
```

Figuring out the next step is beyond my stats.  I'll cheat.

If we imagine that taking the median index element from a bunch of items with mean 0.5 and variance 0.32 is as good as averaging their index...

Let `n` now be the number of elements in our original set.

Then the sum of the indexes of medians of the short sequences has an average of n times n/5*0.5 = `0.1 * n^2`.  The variance of the sum of the indexes of the medians of the short sequences is n times n/5*0.32 = `0.064 * n^2`.

If we then divide the value by n/5 we get:

So mean of n/2 and variance of 1.6.

Oh, if that was true, that would be awesome.  Variance that doesn't grow with the size of `n` means that as `n` gets large, the average index of the medians of the short sequences gets ridiculously tightly distributed.  I guess it makes some sense.  Sadly, we aren't quite doing that -- we want the distribution of the pseudo-median of the medians of the short sequences.  Which is almost certainly worse.

---

Implementation detail.  We can with logarithmic number of memory overhead do an in-place rough median.  (we might even be able to do it without the memory overhead!)

We maintain a vector of 5 indexes with a "nothing here" placeholder.

Each is a successive layer.

At each element, we advance the bottom index.  If it is full, we grab the median, and insert it on the next level up, and clear the bottom layer.

At the end, we complete.

```
using target = std::pair<size_t,std::array<size_t, 5>>;
bool push( target& t, size_t i ) {
  t.second[t.first]=i;
  ++t.first;
  if (t.first==5)
    return true;
}
template<class Container>
size_t extract_median( Container const& c, target& t ) {
  Assert(t.first != 0);
  std::sort( t.data(), t.data()+t.first, [&c](size_t lhs, size_t rhs){
    return c[lhs]<c[rhs];
  } );
  size_t r = t[(t.first+1)/2];
  t.first = 0;
  return r;
}
template<class Container>
void advance(Container const& c, std::vector<target>& targets, size_t i) {
  size_t height = 0;
  while(true) {
    if (targets.size() <= height)
      targets.push_back({});
    if (!push(targets[height], i))
      return;
    i = extract_median(c, targets[height]);
  }
}
template<class Container>
size_t collapse(Container const& c, target* b, target* e) {
  if (b==e) return -1;
  size_t before = collapse(c, b, e-1);
  target& last = (*e-1);
  if (before!=-1)
    push(before, last);
  if (last.first == 0)
    return -1;
  return extract_median(c, last);
}
template<class Container>
size_t rough_median_index( Container const& c ) {
  std::vector<target> targets;
  for (auto const& x:c) {
    advance(c, targets, &x-c.data());
  }
  return collapse(c, targets.data(), targets.data()+targets.size());
}
```

which sketches out how it could work on random access containers.

Comment: This seems to be the [Median of medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) algorithm, unless I'm mistaken, but you don't seem to actually provide the name anywhere.  Seems like it could be a useful reference.

Comment: @GuyGreer *nod*, it is roughly the approximate median step of median of medians, except that part done recursively (instead of recursing+fixing).  The discussion there is good: simply picking a random element (or say, the median of 3-5 or lg(n) random selections) is probably going to be faster and just as good as all the above fancy stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more lookups than insertions into the `vector` you could consider using a data structure which sorts on insertion -- such as `std::set` -- and then use `std::advance()` to get the n'th element in sorted order.

Comment: In the construction of the kd-tree you insert once into the sorted order, then you iterate once over the partition. Then you repeat it on the left and the right side of the partition, recursively. I'm not sure that this solution grants any kind of advantage in this particular case.